# rsnapshot preexec

Tags: backup, rsnapshot

I am mounting my remote backup volume using a rsnapshot cmd_preexec script.

If the /mnt/backup directory doesn't exist when starting rsnapshot i get this error:

```
ERROR: /mnt/backup does not exist.
```

If the directory exists and the preexec mounting fails, it does not stop rsnapshot resulting in the backup being backed up on the completely wrong server...

What should I do about this?

**Edit:**
I know that I could use a wrapper-script, but I don't want to do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh well, looks like i DO have to use a wrapper script.

If anyone has a better idea, feel free to post.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that I could use a wrapper-script, but I don't want to do
>   this..

So you know an easy solution exists. Why not use this?

Anyway, it's even [documented](http://www.rsnapshot.org/faq.html). Set your `snapshot_root` to e.g. `/mnt/remotefs/.snapshot` where `/mnt/remotefs` is the mount point of your remote/loopback fs and also set `no_create_root` to 1. `rsnapshot` will now fail if it can't find it's snapshot root dir.

Comment: Hehe, `ERROR: /mnt/backup/.snapshot does not exist.`

Comment: no_create_root DOES prevent rsnapshot from creating the backup directory. Instead it just stops, as I already pointed out in my initial posting.

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is what you (should) want. Your mount script failed, so you need to prevent `rsnapshot` from doing the backup anyway. What else should it do about this problem? You could enhance your preexec mount script to inform you if it failed so you at least notice it.

Comment: rsnapshot checks if the directory exists BEFORE executing the mount-script. That's what i'm trying to point out.

Comment: And because of this I got to risk backing up to the wrong server, which I really don't want.

Comment: So, you will need a wrapper script in the end.

Comment: Looks like. I was wondering if anyone knew a method on how to tell rsnapshot NOT to behave like this...